# Replacing a div with a command

Tags: html

i've got a site with a lot of phone models, but the code is originally from another part of the site, where the mobiles are only shown when you click on the box, but for this part of the site, I want the mobiles to be shown at anytime, so how do i make this div

```
<div class="submit_filter ans_div" style="display: table;"></div>'
```

into something that just shows without a click?

The site url are [www.findaphone.dk/mobiler](http://findaphone.dk/mobiler)

And as you see, right now there is a big box at the top of the site you have to click on.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No one can make where you are actually stuck in unless you will provide more info with the code that you have tried

Comment: The code works as it is, but i would just like it to work without customers need to click on it. I thought it were maybe possible to just rewrite the div, to a command like-a-thing, i'm sorry for the poor information, i'm really new to this.
What part of the code do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript for this click event is at line 620 of your source code. CTRL+F to find it, it looks like this:

`$(document).on('click','.submit_filter',function () {`

Right now, the line is waiting for a click event on that large button (`.submit_filter`) before executing the code. Replace the line above with this, and the code in that function will trigger on document ready (when the page loads):

`$(document).ready(function () {`

Comment: Thank you so much!! Worked like a charm!